# iMessages sending tiny versions of images/GIFs

Tags: messages, graphics, photos.app, settings

It doesn't seem to matter if I'm sending a personal photo, a GIF, or a video taken straight from iMessage, they're all sent to the recipient as super tiny versions of what I see them being sent as.

I can't find anything in the Messages or Photos settings, so I'm not sure what to do to fix this issue.